# Creating a new column based on entries from another column in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm new in Python and hope you guys can help me with the following:

I have a data frame that contains the daily demand of a certain product. However, the demand is shown cumulative over time. I want to create a column that shows the actual daily demand (see table below).

Current Data frame:

| Day# | Cumulative Demand |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 15 |
| 3 | 38 |
| 4 | 44 |
| 5 | 53 |

What I want to achieve:

| Day# | Cumulative Demand | Daily Demand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | 15 | 5 |
| 3 | 38 | 23 |
| 4 | 44 | 6 |
| 5 | 53 | 9 |

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post any code you have tried?

Comment: Formula would be rather simple, do you not understand df or do you have trouble finding a solution?

Comment: @RussJ, sorry but I'm completely new with Python :(. I'm thinking of iterating across rows to compute for the values in the new column. I have no idea though how to do this.

Comment: @Raumschifffan, I do understand some basics of DF, but I need help on how to build the formula to do this in the new column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, we need the data of the old column

```py
# My Dataframe is called df
demand = df["Cumulative Demand"].tolist()
```

Then recalculate the data

```py
daily_demand = [demand[0]]
for i, d in enumerate(demand[1:]):
    daily_demand.append(d-demand[i])
```

Lastly append the data to a new column

```py
df["Daily Demand"] = daily_demand
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you shared above is representative of your actual data, meaning you have 1 row per day, and Day column is sorted in ascending order.

You can use [`shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) (please read what it does), and perform a subtraction between the cumulative demand, and the shifted version of the cumulative demand. This will give you back the actual daily demand.

To make sure that it works, check whether the cumulative sum of daily demand (the new column) sums to the cumulative sum, using [`cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html).

```
import pandas as pd

# Calculate your Daily Demand column
df['Daily Demand'] = (df['Cumulative Demand'] - df['Cumulative Demand'].shift()).fillna(df['Cumulative Demand'][0])

# Check whether the cumulative sum of daily demands sum up to the Cumulative Demand
>>> all(df['Daily Demand'].cumsum() == df['Cumulative Demand'])
True
```

Will print back:

```
   Day  Cumulative Demand  Daily Demand
0    1                 10          10.0
1    2                 15           5.0
2    3                 38          23.0
3    4                 44           6.0
4    5                 53           9.0
```

Comment: Let me know what part you don't understand, happy to elaborate when I have time

Comment: Thank you! This is straightforward and worked well! Didn't know about the shift function before. :) Thanks again!